# Why does my USB flash drive write performance drop by more than 50% when running Ubuntu vs Windows 10?

Tags: usb-drive, performance, transfer

I found many questions related to poor performance transferring to USB storage, but none matching my situation.

I run dual boot Ubuntu 16.04/Windows 10 on two different machines (one AMD based one Intel).  I consistently observe 41 MB/s transfer rates to a USB flash drive in Ubuntu and 120MB/s on Windows 10.  I performed many different tests and consistently get the same results.  I tested with different file system formats, tools, file sizes, etc.

#### Test 1 - Ubuntu w/Gnome Disks 41.5 MB/s vs Windows 10 w/Crystal Disk Mark 141.154 MB/s

**Gnome Disks on Ubuntu 16.04**

```
Sample Size: 1000.0 MiB (1,048,576,000 bytes)
Average Read Rate: 213.5 MB/s (5 samples)
Average Write Rate: 41.5 MB/s (5 samples)
Average Access Time: 0.46 sec (1000 samples)
```

**Crystal Disk Mark on Windows 10**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskMark 5.2.0 x64 (UWP) (C) 2007-2016 hiyohiyo
                       Crystal Dew World : http://crystalmark.info/
-------------------------------------------------------------------

* MB/s = 1,000,000 bytes/s [SATA/600 = 600,000,000 bytes/s]
* KB = 1000 bytes, KiB = 1024 bytes

   Sequential Read (Q= 32,T= 1) :   230.883 MB/s
  Sequential Write (Q= 32,T= 1) :   141.154 MB/s
     Sequential Read (T= 1) :   333.212 MB/s
    Sequential Write (T= 1) :   125.621 MB/s

  Test : 1024 MiB [D: 0.0% (0.0/29.8 GiB)] (x5)  [Interval=5 sec]
  Date : 2016/11/24 3:25:09
    OS : Windows 10  [10.0 Build 10586] (x64)
```

#### Test 2 - 5 GiB file copy - Ubuntu 40 MiB/s vs Windows 10 98-120 MiB/s

**Ubuntu**

I used a script to flush caches, copy the file using dd and flush caches again.  I call it with time to track run time.

```
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
5368709120 bytes (5.4 GB, 5.0 GiB) copied, 102.44 s, 52.4 MB/s

real    2m7.042s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m10.056s
```

5368709120÷127.042 = 42259324.632798602
42259324.632798602÷1024÷1024 = 40.301632531

~ 40 MiB/s

**Windows 10**

I used a powershell script to copy the same file to USB flash drive and then eject flash drive.  Executed using measure-command to record execution time.  The eject call returns immediately and the operation runs in the background, but in all cases the "safe to remove" screen notification was displayed at the same time as the measure results.

```
PS > measure-command {.\test.ps1}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 42
Milliseconds      : 381
Ticks             : 423816672
TotalDays         : 0.000490528555555556
TotalHours        : 0.0117726853333333
TotalMinutes      : 0.70636112
TotalSeconds      : 42.3816672
TotalMilliseconds : 42381.6672
```

5368709120÷42.382 = 126674274.928035487
126674274.928035487÷1024÷1024 = 120.806002548

~ 120 MiB/s

Even adding a generous 10sec to eject (which appeared instant):

5368709120÷52.382 = 102491487.915696232
102491487.915696232÷1024÷1024 = 97.743499675

~ 98 MiB/s

### Additional details

Log from connecting the USB flash drive in Ubuntu:

```
[  350.460108] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  350.477525] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05dc, idProduct=a212
[  350.477532] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  350.477537] usb 2-1: Product: USB Flash Drive
[  350.477540] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Lexar
[  350.477543] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[  350.501276] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  350.502121] scsi host8: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  350.502218] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  350.503430] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  351.501106] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Lexar    USB Flash Drive  PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  351.502007] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  351.503962] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] 62586880 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 GB/29.8 GiB)
[  351.504490] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  351.504501] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 2b 00 00 08
[  351.505598] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  351.638276]  sda: sda1
[  351.640491] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  351.818131] [EXFAT] trying to mount...
[  351.824012] [EXFAT] mounted successfully
```

Ubuntu Test Scripts:

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo sh -c "sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
time ./cmd.sh
```

cmd.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

dd if=./lf of=/media/flashdrive/lf bs=5M
sudo sh -c "sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

Windows Test Script:

test.ps1:

```
cp lf D:/.
$driveEject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application
$driveEject.NameSpace(17).ParseName("D:").InvokeVerb("Eject")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with different block sizes in dd when testing Ubuntu? I have found that in many systems (computer hardware + software) it works well with bs=4096. I notice, that you have used a huge block size, bs=5M.

Maybe it will work better with a smaller block size, maybe 4096, maybe some value 'between mine and yours'. You can also try with some other tool (not dd but for example cp, which selects the block size automatically).

The history is also important. To make a fair comparison, it is a good idea to start with a blank pendrive, where you have written zeros to all memory cells. See this link

[Restore the original speed](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Comment: I tried with different block sizes.  The performance seems to plateau  at bs=1024.  I get the same performance with cp.  I used dd in this example for the detailed output.

Comment: The drive was brand new and blank when I started.  The performance has not varied since I started testing.  I would also think that any performance degradation caused by flash drive content/history would affect Windows and Ubuntu uniformly.

Comment: Well, I think you made a good test. I'm sorry to find that Ubuntu is slower than Windows, but it is not your fault. One the contrary, now that we know, maybe the Ubuntu performance can be improved. I think this is something very fundamental and probably common with all linux distros.

Comment: Just one more question: Did you test 64-bit systems of both Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: Both are 64 bit.  I ran similar tests with a USB 3 hard drive.  I consistently get 68 MiB/sec on Windows 10 and Ubuntu.  Whatever the issue, it appears specific to USB flash drives not USB storage in general.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks again for sharing this information :-)